# DialogFragment with fixed header, scrollable body and fixed footer

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout, android-dialogfragment

I want to show a dialog with a title (header), body (content) and accept button (footer). I want header and footer to be visible even if content is longer than the screen height. If this is the case, I want body to be scrollable so that it can shrink. Here is what I tried, scrollView gets all the dialog space, no header and no footer is shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:minWidth="300dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="Title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bodyContainer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bodyContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonContainer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1500dp"
                android:text="Long text" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bodyContainer" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try `fillViewport =true`  to scrollview

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your `ScrollView's` height is set to `wrap_content` the constraints will not limit the dimension if it gets too big to satisfy them. To fix this and enforce the top and bottom constraints, set `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` for your `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know why it doesn't work when ScrollView's `height` is set to `0dp` and there are constraints defined for top and bottom?

Comment: It's because the height of the root `ConstraintLayout` is also `wrap_content` so the `ScrollView` doesn't how much space it has to fill. If you set it to `match_parent` on the `ConstraintLayout` then the `0dp` on the `ScrollView` should work too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is exactly what you just want. Use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="300dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:text="Title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bodyContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1500dp"
            android:text="Long text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```